# Halloween Restrictions?

Tags: halal-haram, source-identification

Salam, I have been looking into Halloween and found out that it's haram to celebrate it which makes perfect sense. However I have a few questions regrading its restrictions:

1) If my friend gives me candy and I save it (because I don't want to waste food or make him feel bad )and eat it a  couple days later,when Halloween is OVER, will it still count as me taking part of the celebration?

2) If my teacher gives us no hw or classwork in "honor of Halloween"
Did I commit the sin for celebrating it?

3) If my teacher makes us play Halloween games or do activities what should I do? 
I can't really say anything because they will just be like "oh its just for fun no worries" 
I need an answer because tomorrow is Halloween.

Comment: A fast answer: Basically you should try to avoid accepting any thing related to that and have in mind that your intention is important, if you reject (or have in mind to reject the celebration) it you basically don't celebrate it, 1) you still could tell your friends that you couldn't accept candies (before halloween), but taking it under the described intention might be ok 2) here you have no choice, you could still study by yourself instead 3) you may define your position on the celebration and not join them or play (this basically has no direct link to celebration). You could repent later!

Comment: @Medi1Saif please refrain from answering in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Actually origin of Halloween comes from pagan belief and celebration of  All Hallows Eve . They used to offer sacrifices and treats . They used to wear disguises as part of this satanic celebration. The origin of Halloween is well known and you can look it up.

It is absolutely not fun and celebration and something harmless as some of you might think .

True believer should not take part in anything that has satanic roots and there to stray you away from Gods mercy .  I never dress my children and make them beg for candy . They are Muslim children and I would not degrade them by begging candy door to door for something labeled as “ fun” instead that day I show them why Halloween is wrong to use it at teaching moment and watch movies and have snacks “ halal o ween”

If your teacher asks you to write about Halloween , write about origins of this evil pagan tradition . I’m sure many Christians and Jews regardless of what they believe would like to know why a Muslim would not take part in pagan tradition .

Comment: Note that Jews and many Christians share this opinion

Answer (score -1):

Actually, taking part in such celebrations as fun festivals and mere cultural, not praising a certain wrong belief or improper person, is not problematic by itself, as long as, no forbidden thing will be commited. For example, you have kids and they want to dress fancy like cartoons once a year, it is not that bad to be forbidden. Note that according to Quran, the non believers in the beginning of Islam used to do Hadj, though in a wrong manner. Islam didn't said it is forbidden for Muslims to do Hadj because the non-believers also do it in their own way, but only omitted the wrong deeds added to it after the Ibraheem's (PBUH) era, and made it the way it should have been.

But if a whole celebration is to preach a wrong belief, even if a little, even if implicitly (*this depends on you, and on the common sense of the society in which you live, how you understand it*), then your questions will find place to be asked, then:

1. from what you say, and how you state it, it is clear that you don't like to take part in what you know is wrong, so if eating the candy given to you by your friend is Halal for you, you can eat it. If you think eating it in public means accompanying the crowd, then you can eat it when you're alone, right at the time or days after will not make difference, AFAIK.
2. no, it is not in your set of choices. Sins are meaningful if you have a choice not to do it ... and intention is the key point here
3. straight forward from the answers given to your first two points

So late an answer, but may help another person, as such celebrations appear regularly each year ... :)

Answer (score -2):

Halloween would be haram if it was actually taken seriously. But it isn't. When it's said to be a 'celebration', it's not a celebration of certain beliefs. It's merely a festivity of a kind and generally seen to be fun, and something that everyone can join in. Very few people today, after all, actually believe in ghosts, witches and the like.

Intention after all matters in Islam, and there is no intention here to lead people astray from Islam. If anything, people will find it baffling that Islam would be against this because of the reasoning given above - that is, there are no serious beliefs involved here.